# IE CSS Incompatibility

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

How is should be:
http://thc-cup.ucoz.com/How_is_should_be_Chrome_and_Firefox.png

How bad it is on IE:
http://thc-cup.ucoz.com/How_bad_it_is_on_IE.png

Is there any way to make the avatar area display like on Chrome and Firefox?

Link: thc-cup.ucoz.com/forum/2-1-1

CSS from that box:

```
.postTdInfo { 
text-align:center;
background:#e0e0e0;
display: inline-block; 
margin: 0px 0px 0px 35px; 
padding: 1px; 
border: 1px solid #cfcfcf; 
background: #e0e0e0; 
border-radius: 5px; 
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Try to validate your code first : http://validator.w3.org/check?verbose=1&uri=http%3A%2F%2Fthc-cup.ucoz.com%2Fforum%2F2-1-1

Comment: Fix the errors in the page first. It's terrible.

Comment: You should also mention that you are using tables everywhere. That might be helping your issue

Comment: @fmsf No. IE is compatible with tables.

Answer (score 0):

I think this script can help you out [CSS3 PIE](http://css3pie.com/)